# Restar un número cada cierta cantidad

Tags: php, html, mysql

soy nuevo por estos rumbos, estoy atorado con una petición, tengo que multiplicar un precio = 300 pesos cada 10 boletos, y por ejemplo el 11, 22, 33 y asi no se consideran para multiplicar, es decir, cada diez boletos vendidos se regala uno, tengo lo siguiente

```
while($rowBoletos = mysqli_fetch_array($model->resBoletos)){

        $cargo = floatval($rowBoletos['tboletos'])* 300; //floatval($model->precio);

        $tabla .= '<tr>
            <td width="20%">'.$rowBoletos['nombre'].'</td>
            <td width="5%">'.$rowBoletos['numero_unico'].'</td>
            <td width="10%">'.$rowBoletos['estatus'].'</td>
            <td width="5%" align="center">'.number_format($rowBoletos['tboletos']).'</td>
                    <td width="10%" align="center">&#36; '.number_format($cargo).'</td>';
```

donde en la variable $cargo se deben restar 300 pesos cada 3000, si el valor de 'tboletos' es 22 el resultado debe ser 6000 y no 6600.

Saludos.

Comment: Bienvenido a Stack Overflow en español! Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Puedes descontar el numero de boletos necesarios usando `floor()` asi:

```
while($rowBoletos = mysqli_fetch_array($model->resBoletos)){

    $cargo = floatval($rowBoletos['tboletos'])* 300; //floatval($model->precio);
    $descuento = floor($rowBoletos['tboletos']/11) * 300;
    $cargo -= $descuento;

    $tabla .= '<tr>
        <td width="20%">'.$rowBoletos['nombre'].'</td>
        <td width="5%">'.$rowBoletos['numero_unico'].'</td>
        <td width="10%">'.$rowBoletos['estatus'].'</td>
        <td width="5%" align="center">'.number_format($rowBoletos['tboletos']).'</td>
                <td width="10%" align="center">&#36; '.number_format($cargo).'</td>';
```

Comment: Hola alanfcm muchas gracias, si, con eso funcionó, me esta mostrando los resultados que esperaba, muchas gracias nuevamente

Comment: @EnriqueSanchez no es necesario que agradezcas. Si la respuesta te sirvio, marcala como aceptado en esta misma pregunta usando el tilde a la izquierda de la misma.